# Angular pass input value to $rootScope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

I have situation where I want to use **$rootScope** variable and update its value with the one entered in input field. I have sitauation code shortened to this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/55j35/117/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo" placeholder="Enter something" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="doSomething()" value="Send" ng-disabled="foo == null" />
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.foo = null;
    $scope.doSomething = function () {
        alert("Hello, " + $rootScope.foo);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to pass input value to **$rootScope** variable would be great!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  `$rootScope` should not be used for holding data.  Use a service.

Comment: I do actually need to share this value between two controllers and I have 0 practice with services, as I am new to angular.

Comment: You can use a service just like you're using `$rootScope`, just create a property on the service that holds `foo` and assign to it.  Services are singletons so they persist through the lifetime of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not recommended, Still if you want you can do it the following way

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo" placeholder="Enter something" ng-change="onFooChange()" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="doSomething()" value="Send" ng-disabled="foo == null" />
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.foo = null;

    $scope.onFooChange = function(){
     $rootScope.foo = angular.copy($scope.foo);
    }

    $scope.doSomething = function () {
        alert("Hello, " + $rootScope.foo);
    }
}
```

When the value of text field is changed `onFooChange` function is called and the value is stored into `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach without using `ng-change`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.foo=null;
    $scope.doSomething = function () {
    $rootScope.foo=$scope.foo;
        alert("Hello, " + $rootScope.foo);
    }
}
```